# How to list commits in one branch

Tags: git

I have two branches: master and feature that merged before, How do I just show all commits from master branch using commands like `git log`?[image]

Comment: From master _what_? From master _on feature_? From master _prior to feature_? Please revise to be more clear. It would help if you'd reference the commit names from your diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing you can get is to only display *first parents* :

```
git log --first-parent master
git log --first-parent --graph --oneline master
```

Answer (score 0):

git log --first-parent
should work